# Need help on an odd Windows XP situation

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I know there's no support for my situation but I'm wondering how to stop the following:

1. The system, an old computer server I use that only works with Windows XP, wouldn't boot. Upon restarting it would just reboot in an endless cycle. Booting into Safe Mode ended up causing the computer to reboot at mup.sys file.
2. I read online that I could repair the mup.sys so I put in a Windows XP sp3 disk and it didn't give me a repair option so I pressed an installation button. This loaded and I couldn't stop it so I waited until the install was there then it restarted and tried to install Windows XP SP 3.
3. I'm not sure the program I have will work with Windows XP SP 3 it's an older model Voice Mail system and I can't let it install because this is a custom built unit and the Voice Mail would have to be reprogrammed completely.

So the summary here is when I boot up the computer it goes into the Windows XP installation mode and I stop it. How can I stop the installation from happening. I pulled the disk so that it doesn't do the install but when I boot up it goes right back to installation. Is there a way to just abort the installation and leave the computer not working, but also not doing this update?

Finally, I went into Safe Mode to try and fix it but, as before, it just stops at mup.sys. If I try to get into the SP 3 it's of course in installation mode and will not go into safe mode.

So how do I completely stop the system from trying to install the SP 3 from a command line or something if I cannot get into Safe Mode. Here's a pic of the screen giving me some options but I'm unlcear where to go next.

I have:
Safe Mode
Safe with Networking
Safe with Command Prompt

Enable Boot Logging
Enable VGA Mode
Last Known Good Configuration
Directory Services Restore Mode
Debugging Mode
Disable Automatic restart on system failure

Start Windows Normally
Rebooot
Return to OS Choice Menu.

I just want to stop the installation on reboot at this point and then find a way to repair the mup.sys file.

Answer (score 0):

Select Last Known Good Configuration and reboot pc
If problem is still not resolved, then try to restore to an earlier restore point.